# Selecting sorted data from two different data sources

Tags: java, android, cursor

I need the most updated image, and I need to select from two different places. How do I do this?

Below is my code, and it returns only from `/dcim/camera`, not from eye-fi when it should be able to return from both.

```
private void PopulateDataSource() {
    if (_context == null) return;

    if(_context.getContentResolver() != null) {
        final ContentResolver cr = _context.getContentResolver();

    String[] projections = new String[] {
        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA };
        String sortOrder = String.format(
            "%s limit 10", Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC"); 

    final String[] selectionArgs = { 
        getBucketId(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +
        "/Eye-Fi"),
        getBucketId(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +
        "/DCIM/Camera") };

    final String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID + " = ?";

    try {
        // select all images from DataBase and set it in Cursor
        SearchCursor = cr.query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projections, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

        } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Cursor failed", ex.getMessage());
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your selection string with the following:

```
final String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID + " IN (?, ?)";
```

Comment: Thank's it's a correct!
One more addition to your answer, i had to sort it by _ID and that's worked perfectly!